# rsyslog not logging

Tags: systemd, syslog, rsyslog

This is an odd issue.

I was testing the chrony/ntp services on a RHEL7 VM and was resetting its time as well as the host's. Once I was satisfied with it I checked `/var/log/messages` and realized it hadn't been changed in a while.

Now no matter what I do nothing is being logged except for when I restart the rsyslog service itself; when I do I get this:

```
Apr 15 13:59:43 mymachine1 rsyslogd: [origin software="rsyslogd" swVersion="7.4.2" x-pid="2847" x-info="http://www.rsyslog.com"] exiting on signal 2.

Apr 15 13:59:59 mymachine1 rsyslogd: [origin software="rsyslogd" swVersion="7.4.2" x-pid="2853" x-info="http://www.rsyslog.com"] start

Apr 15 14:00:11 mymachine1 rsyslogd-3000: sd_journal_get_cursor() failed: 'Cannot assign requested address'
```

Trying things like `logger test` don't log, nothing else except rsyslog's own messages seems to. When I run rsyslog manually with `-n -N1` as arguments I get:

```
rsyslogd: version 7.4.2, config validation run (level 1), master config /etc/rsyslog.conf

rsyslogd: End of config validation run. Bye
```

It just seems like nothing can log through rsyslog for some reason. And a second identical VM on the same host (which didn't go through quite the same circle of repeatedly disabling ntp, having the date changed and rebooted multiple times) with the same rsyslog.conf file logs just fine.

At this point the date/time is correct, chrony is enabled and running, and I've rebooted several times - after 30 seconds of kernel messages nothing else gets logged again.

Thoughts?

Comment: I haven't used RHEL7 before but I'd check `/etc/rsyslog.conf` and the `/etc/rsyslog.d` directories. It sounds like you don't have anything configured to be routed to a particular log file. You might also try specifying a syslog message with `EMERG` priority to see if that gets through. Example: `logger -p EMERG not really an emergency`

Comment: /etc/rsyslog.conf contains this:

    *.info;mail.none;authpriv.none;cron.none;local0.none    /var/log/messages

As for files in /etc/rsyslog.d, listen.conf, this:

    $SystemLogSocketName /run/systemd/journal/syslog

and rate-unlimit.conf this:

    $SystemLogRateLimitInterval 0
    $SystemLogRateLimitBurst 0

As for the EMERG priority, it doesn't get logged either.

Comment: You should probably either update your answer or pastebin that since we lost the line breaks there.

Comment: Sorry about that. For some reason it won't parse linefeeds in comments.

When I comment this out in rsyslog.conf logging is enabled again: $OmitLocalLogging on . However on my other identical VM on the same host it's not commented out and logging works fine.

Comment: Looking into it, apparently that's an option for `systemd` (which RHEL7 migrated to, IIRC) Can you check `journalctl -b` to see if your logs are going to the systemd journal?

Comment: Yes, the systemd journal is working fine. Even with $OmitLocalLogging on (at which point /var/log/messages isn't being updated) it's receiving logs.

Comment: So the messages are likely going to the `systemd` journal and just not going to syslog when you tell it to OmitLocalLogging. That's expected because OmitLocalLogging disables `systemd`'s ability to relay from journal to syslog (to keep from retaining redundant info I suppose). Is the other VM also RHEL7? I'd start looking at the journal configuration differences.

Comment: If the other VM is RHEL7, then the systemd journal is probably relaying logs to `rsyslog` using some other means.

Comment: Yes, the other VM is RHEL7 - same host, installed from the same .iso, configured through the same puppet master. The only difference between them is one got its date changed a bunch of times and rebooted with ntp/chrony off, until at some point I realized nothing was getting logged in /var/log/messages.

Comment: At this point I'm not really in my area of expertise. All I can really say is [the effect you're seeing where OmitLocalLogging stops relaying messages to rsyslog is apparently intended](http://serverfault.com/questions/565254/what-kind-of-messages-are-dropped-when-omitlocallogging-is-on). At this point it seems to be more a question of why the other system _is_ able to relay the logs despite having local logging disabled. Looks like there's a `imjournal` module for `rsyslog` so you might look to see if that's how they're getting into syslog.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Not a direct solution but I would enable some debugging to see what's happening behind the scenes.

#### Idea #1 - Debugging logger

For starters when you run your `logger` commands you can do them like so, echoing out messages to STDERR.

```
$ logger -s "hi"
saml: hi
```

#### Idea #2 - validate your configuration file

You can also try validating your rsyslog configuration file:

```
$ sudo rsyslogd -N6 | head -10
rsyslogd: version 7.2.6, config validation run (level 6), master config /etc/rsyslog.conf
rsyslogd: End of config validation run. Bye.

6921.173842409:7f8b11df2780: rsyslogd 7.2.6 startup, module path '', cwd:/root
6921.175241008:7f8b11df2780: caller requested object 'net', not found (iRet -3003)
6921.175261977:7f8b11df2780: Requested to load module 'lmnet'
6921.175272711:7f8b11df2780: loading module '/lib64/rsyslog/lmnet.so'
6921.175505384:7f8b11df2780: module lmnet of type 2 being loaded (keepType=0).
6921.175520208:7f8b11df2780: entry point 'isCompatibleWithFeature' not present in module
6921.175528413:7f8b11df2780: entry point 'setModCnf' not present in module
6921.175535294:7f8b11df2780: entry point 'getModCnfName' not present in module
6921.175541502:7f8b11df2780: entry point 'beginCnfLoad' not present in module
```

#### Idea #3 - Turn up rsyslogd debugging

Also I'd try enabling debugging of the `rsyslogd` daemon for further insight.

```
$ sudo -i
$ export RSYSLOG_DEBUGLOG="/tmp/debuglog"
$ export RSYSLOG_DEBUG="Debug"

$ service rsyslog stop
$ rsyslogd -d | head -10    
7160.005597645:7fae096a3780: rsyslogd 7.2.6 startup, module path '', cwd:/root
7160.005872662:7fae096a3780: caller requested object 'net', not found (iRet -3003)
7160.005895004:7fae096a3780: Requested to load module 'lmnet'
7160.005906331:7fae096a3780: loading module '/lib64/rsyslog/lmnet.so'
7160.006023505:7fae096a3780: module lmnet of type 2 being loaded (keepType=0).
7160.006030872:7fae096a3780: entry point 'isCompatibleWithFeature' not present in module
7160.006033780:7fae096a3780: entry point 'setModCnf' not present in module
7160.006036209:7fae096a3780: entry point 'getModCnfName' not present in module
7160.006038359:7fae096a3780: entry point 'beginCnfLoad' not present in module
...
...
7160.006063913:7fae096a3780: rsyslog runtime initialized, version 7.2.6, current users 1
7160.006102179:7fae096a3780: source file syslogd.c requested reference for module 'lmnet', reference count now 2
7160.006113657:7fae096a3780: GenerateLocalHostName uses 'greeneggs'
```

#### Confirming version info

```
$ rsyslogd -version
rsyslogd 7.2.6, compiled with:
    FEATURE_REGEXP:             Yes
    FEATURE_LARGEFILE:          No
    GSSAPI Kerberos 5 support:      Yes
    FEATURE_DEBUG (debug build, slow code): No
    32bit Atomic operations supported:  Yes
    64bit Atomic operations supported:  Yes
    Runtime Instrumentation (slow code):    No
    uuid support:               Yes

See http://www.rsyslog.com for more information.
```

#### Confirmed bug and a workaround

The OP submitted this as a bug to Red Hat.

- [Bug 1088021 - Changing a VM host's time disables rsyslog file logging](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1088021).

The bug was characterized as follows:

> Sure enough when I set the host's own time the VM had the same wrong time as the host. That's when I noticed /var/log/messages was no longer being updated.
>
> It turns out nothing other than restarting the rsyslog service itself logs to files at that point. If I do so this gets logged:
>
> ```
>   ---
>    Apr 15 16:39:39 rhel7time-dev rsyslogd-3000: sd_journal_get_cursor() failed: 'Cannot assign requested address'
>
>   Apr 15 16:39:39 rhel7time-dev rsyslogd: [origin software="rsyslogd" swVersion="7.4.2" x-pid="574" x-info="http://www.rsyslog.com"] exiting on signal 15.
>   Apr 15 16:39:39 rhel7time-dev rsyslogd: [origin software="rsyslogd" swVersion="7.4.2" x-pid="2117" x-info="http://www.rsyslog.com"] start
>   ---
> ```
>
> Otherwise nothing is logged to file, including logger.
>
> If I comment out $OmitLocalLogging on in rsyslog.conf then file logging resumes (notice that until that point I hadn't changed rsyslog.conf).
>
> Logging through journal is unaffected by all this. journalctl -b shows logging, including anything sent by logger.

To which the one of the developers responded:

> When this issue occurs, you can delete `/var/lib/rsyslog/imjournal.state` and restart the daemon as a workaround.
>
> rsyslog doesn't handle the date directly but only through the systemd API.
>   I've checked the code in imjournal a while ago and this looks like an issue in systemd.
>
> For reference, see: https://github.com/rsyslog/rsyslog/issues/43

Comment: I brought this up as a bug report and got a response from RedHat. Details can be seen at https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1088021 .

This is closed for now, thanks everyone for your help. :)

Comment: @Arkandel - thanks for closing the loop on this. I've incorporated your findings and the workaround into this A so we can close the Q&A cycle as resolved (at least in the sense that it's a confirmed bug w/ a workaround). Please mark this A as accepted if you agree w/ this synopsis.

Answer (score 7):

In my case `systemctl restart systemd-journald` helped, because

```
File /run/log/journal/29c32d60f93c42489aabb4ebeb593f5b/system.journal corrupted or uncleanly shut down, renaming and replacing.
[12274404.541271] systemd-journald[15492]: Deleted empty journal /run/log/journal/29c32d60f93c42489aabb4ebeb593f5b/system@0005317804680d96-e103c48634d16856.journal~ (4096 bytes).
```

Comment: Commenting so that people would know. I had the same error like OP. I didn't have error message like the one in this answer, but I tried the command anyway. Strangely enough, my rsyslog is working now.

Comment: `sudo service rsyslog restart` worked for me.  Great idea!

Answer (score 4):

Try to check rsyslog conf with: **rsyslogd -f /etc/rsyslog.conf -N 1**
If everything  is ok try to restart systemd-journald.socket with:
**systemctl restart systemd-journald.socket**
you can use the command "logger" to check if rsyslog work or not: **logger "hello"**

Answer (score 3):

There's a surprising fragile dependency between journald and rsyslogd, especially in RHEL7. Journald becomes the first, canonical log handler. It should handle logs sent to `/dev/log` and forward them on to rsyslogd. However, very default installations of rsyslogd will try to read from `/dev/log`. The RHEL package managers do circumvent that by adding a directive

```
$SystemLogSocketName /run/systemd/journal/syslog
```

That is the path to a socket that the rsyslog creates and that `systemd-journald.socket` will write to. That unit also creates `/dev/log` and triggers the start of `systemd-journald.service`.

But if for some reason, that directive is missing *or* there is a non-fatal error in the `rsyslogd` configuration somewhere, it will use the default `/dev/log` and *recreate* that socket so that it can listen. This has two effects:

- messages sent by processes to `/dev/log` will not reach journald.
- journald messages will not reach rsyslogd

So, to debug this, you can restart the rsyslog service and check the timestamp on `/dev/log`. If the times match up, you've got a config error somewhere or it is missing that directive.

Comment: This great answer tells the whole story of the flow. Here is just a reminder to try to systemctl restart systemd-journald.socket and then rsyslog.