# rsyslog service mulfuction after server reboot

Tags: centos, syslog, rsyslog

We recently faced an issue with `rsyslog` service on CentOS-7. 
This server was running for like 2-3 years continuously and we rebooted it last night. Since then `rsyslogs` are not written.

[Tried steps given here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/124942/rsyslog-not-logging)
By restarting both `systemd-journald.socket` and `rsyslog`.

Following is our `/etc/rsyslog.conf`

```
## STATS COLLECTION ##
module(load="impstats" interval="10" resetCounters="on" log.file="/tmp/stats" log.syslog="off" severity="7")
$DebugFile /var/log/rsyslog_debug.log
$DebugLevel 2


#### MODULES ####
module(load="imuxsock" SysSock.Use="off")
module(load="imjournal" StateFile="imjournal.state")

#### GLOBAL DIRECTIVES ####
global(workDirectory="/var/lib/rsyslog")

module(load="imudp" threads="10" timeRequery="1" batchSize="256")
#listeners
input(type="imudp" port="514" ruleset="writeRemoteData")

ruleset(name="writeRemoteData"
   queue.type="fixedArray"
   queue.size="250000"
   queue.dequeueBatchSize="4096"
   queue.workerThreads="8"
   queue.workerThreadMinimumMessages="60000"
   ) {
   action(type="omfile" file="/home/myuser/A10fw.log"
          ioBufferSize="64M" flushOnTXEnd="off"
          asyncWriting="on")
}

# Include all config files in /etc/rsyslog.d/
#include(file="/etc/rsyslog.d/\*.conf" mode="optional")

# #### RULES ####
*.info;mail.none;authpriv.none;cron.none                /var/log/messages
authpriv.*                                              /var/log/secure
mail.*                                                  -/var/log/maillog
cron.*                                                  /var/log/cron
*.emerg                                                 :omusrmsg:*
uucp,news.crit                                          /var/log/spooler
local7.*                                                /var/log/boot.log

$template logFormat,"%rawmsg%\n"
$ActionFileDefaultTemplate logFormat
```

`rsyslogd -f /etc/rsyslog.conf -N 1` shows no errors.

We can use `logging` with `-n host` option reflects on `/home/myuser/A10fw.log` file, but not `logging "Hi"`

What do we missing here? Feel free to ask any clarification questions.